# Adding number to custom field in Ultimate Member after purchase with WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I am trying to activate a code every time that a person purchased a product on my website. I am not very familiar with the coding in php in WordPress. I have used Pods to create custom user fields. I have Snippets making the coding.

The general idea is after a person buys something the code would fire looking for any products that have a specific tag. If it has that tag, the code then adds to the custom user field in Pods.

```
function increase_digital_product_count($order_id) {
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();
$digital_product_dex = pods_field('user', $user_id, 'dexterity');
$digital_product_int = pods_field('user', $user_id, 'intelligence');
$digital_product_str = pods_field('user', $user_id, 'strength');

// Loop through items in the order
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) 
{
    $product = $item->get_product();
    
    // Check if the item is a virtual product
    if ($product && $product->is_virtual()) 
    {
        $tags = $product->get_tag_ids();
        
        // Check the tags of the virtual product to determine which field to update
        if (in_array('dex', $tags)) 
        {
            $digital_product_dex += 1;
        } 
        elseif (in_array('int', $tags)) 
        {
            $digital_product_int += 1;
        }  
        elseif (in_array('str', $tags)) 
        {
            $digital_product_str += 1;
        }
        
        // Save the updated value to Pods
        pods('user', $user_id)->save(array('dexterity' => $digital_product_dex,));
        pods('user', $user_id)->save(array('intelligence' => $digital_product_int,));
        pods('user', $user_id)->save(array('strength' => $digital_product_int,));
    }
}
}add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'increase_digital_product_count');
```